# Including and referencing a XSL file in Eclipse plugin build

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am developing my first plugin for eclipse. I'd like to include somehow an XSLT file in the build so I can use it in plugin source code.

For example, my plugin adds a new option in right-click menu for XML files: "Do XSL Transformation". After clicking that option I want my plugin to perform a XSL transformation on selected file using one specific file.

So the question is, how to include the XSL file in plugin build, and how to reference it in plugin code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post is a bit old, but since I struggled a bit on that one... Here are the steps I followed :

Add the xsl file (or whatever file) in your project.

In build.properties, include the xsl file.

In any class, access your file with the following code :

```
InpuStream xslIS = this.getClass().getRessourceAsStream("/myXSLFile");
```

Comment: I did it in a bit different way, also I added file in build.properties, but then accessed the file using the following code: `new File(FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("/addins/smrl/odf2shore.xslt"), Collections.EMPTY_MAP)).toURI());`